# Phone makes me dial 1 before answering a call

Tags: sync, google-voice, call-screening

I have a Samsung Galaxy S5. Every call gets synced to my computer and I can't retrieve calls until I press the number **1**. I miss most of my calls. This is undesirable. Please help me.

Comment: It's call-screening in Google-voice settings. Turn off the option.

Answer (score 1):

This happens when Call screening is turned ON in [Google voice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Voice) settings.

1. Go to [Google Voice Settings in Web interface](https://www.google.com/voice)
2. Go to *Settings* (gear icon) → *Calls* tab.
3. Uncheck *Call screening*

Source : [Phone makes me dial 1 before answering](http://forums.androidcentral.com/sprint-galaxy-nexus/180855-phone-makes-me-dial-1-before-answering.html#post1858143)